# error: package directory <package> does not exist

Tags: python, pypi

I already checked the other answers but they didn't help me.

I'd like to upload a package on pypi and this is my setup https://del.dog/vozeworazu.py

When I try to run python setup.py sdist I get this error

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing LootGameBotApi.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to LootGameBotApi.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to LootGameBotApi.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to LootGameBotApi.egg-info\top_level.txt
error: package directory 'LootGameApi' does not exist
```

I've tried to put in packages the directory and it worked but when I tried to import it it said it couldn't find the module

Comment: You obviously don't have a package directory `LootGameApi` even though your `setup.py` says yous should have one (see the `packages` option). Create a directory `LootGameApi`, add an `__init__.py` file there and eventually move the rest of your code into this directory.